# States on ServiceNow API

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, servicenow

I am surfing [servicenow api](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=SOAP_Direct_Web_Service_API#getRecords) to know about the names of each states. But I can't able to find out state's information from this site.

Till now, I found out only 1 state's name which is `Approved` - State Number - `8` from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29232613/getrecords-that-are-approved-in-servicenow-api). Likewise, I want to know each `state` names from 1 to 10 or till what number it exists. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

John,
"State" is just a field on a table. Different types of records may have different options for their states, or may not have a state field at all. They may have multiple fields which denote different types of states, each with their own possible values.

You need to look at the dictionary entries for each "state" field you care about- for each record type- and see what the choice options defined for each one is individually.

Answer (score 0):

-5 'On hold'
0 'New'
1 'Open'
2 'In Progress'
3 'Closed'
6 'Resolved'
7 'Canceled'

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).